# Schedule an alarm on device reboot automatically in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to build an application which checks for notification files on a server, every hour. I used the alarm manager class to implement this. But I am unable to implement the automatic start on reboot part. I want that the alarm should run periodically after reboot. Can some one please tell me how to go about doing it.

This is my MyAlarmReceiver Class.

```
package com.example.quickstart;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.example.quickstart.alarm";

    // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
      //  i.putExtra("username", username);
        context.startService(i);
    }


}
```

This is my  NotificationBootReceiver Class.

```
package com.example.quickstart;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class NotificationBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
            // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
            final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                    i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Setup periodic alarm every every half hour from this point onwards
            long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
            // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    2*60*60,pIntent);
            // alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            //    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest file looks like this(it's not the complete manifest file but the relevant parts)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name=".NotificationBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The notifications are working fine, but what I want is the start  notifications automatically on reboot feature. When i reboot the notification feature does not work,i.e, the alarm does not go off. And also the android documentation says ***(this only works if the app has already been launched by the user at least once)*** , is there a way to set the alarm automatically on reboot without launching the app. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Documentation link [android devs link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)
(Go to: Start an alarm when the device restarts)

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible to set the alarms without starting the app even once. Once the app has been started the alarms can be triggered.

Comment: Is there a work around to this, is there a way I can launch an activity of the app on reboot, I looked it up but could not get an answer that works. Please help.

Comment: For any of the Broadcast Receiver/Alarm to work the app needs to be opened atleast once. The Application class needs to be invoked which will set those up. No other work around.

Comment: Can we achieve automated triggering of a service using work manager?